# Place to recruit beta testers

Tags: webapp-rec

Where can I find a place to recruit beta testers for our web apps?

Is it best to create an holding page which collects name, email etc or is they a site where I can go to etc?

Comment: Please define _best_. Otherwise, question is ambiguous. Possibly, rephrase along the lines: "Is there a tool to promote my beta?" and/or "How can I simplify registration of beta-testers for me and for the testers?". Otherwise, there won't be a definitive answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not saying that this is the best way to do it, but here is how I'm doing it right now.

I have a website ([step1tuts.com](http://step1tuts.com)), where I announce the project I'm working on, and saying that it's coming soon. At the bottom, I just have a form generated by google docs spreadsheets, where people can sign up to be a beta tester. When I think that my site's prototype is ready, I'm going to feed the csv file into my database to insert the first users.